# UIPickerView Maximum Width in iOS 9

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios9, uipickerview

I have an app that uses a UIPickerView to set various parameters having to do with line style for a graph series (line width, colour, and line style).   This picker is used in a table view row.  I have defined the frame for the picker so that its width fills the width of the cell's contentView member.  Up until iOS 9, this appeared to work.  With iOS 9, there appears to be some sort of maximum cap on the width of a UIPickerView.  Has anyone encountered anything similar to this?

The picker view is being created like this:

```
self.picker = [[[UIPickerView alloc] init] autorelease];
[self.contentView addSubview:self.picker];
self.picker.dataSource = self;
self.picker.delegate = self;
self.picker.backgroundColor = [UIColor grouped_table_view_background_colour];
```

The cell is layed out as follows:

```
-(void) layoutSubviews
{
   // we need to allow the base class to perform its layout.
   static CGFloat left_margin = 40;
   static CGFloat right_margin = 40;
   CGSize my_size;
   [super layoutSubviews];
   my_size = self.contentView.bounds.size;
   my_size.width -= left_margin + right_margin;

   // we now need to lay out the views.
   CGRect picker_rect = CGRectMake(left_margin, 5, my_size.width, my_size.height);
   self.picker.frame = picker_rect;

   // we want to look at the bounds of the picker
   CGRect picker_bounds = self.picker.bounds;
   NSLog(@"picker bounds x=%g, y=%g, w=%g, h=%g",  picker_bounds.origin.x, picker_bounds.origin.y, picker_bounds.size.width, picker_bounds.size.height);
}
```

I am also overloading the widthForComponent method as follows:

```
-(CGFloat) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView widthForComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
   // we want to look at the bounds of the picker
   CGRect picker_bounds = self.picker.bounds;
   NSLog(@"picker bounds x=%g, y=%g, w=%g, h=%g", picker_bounds.origin.x, picker_bounds.origin.y, picker_bounds.size.width, picker_bounds.size.height);
   return picker_bounds.size.width / 3;
}
```

I can see that the bounds of the view appear correctly both in the values that are logged as well as the background colour of the view.  Despite this, the picker appears to fill less than half the width that is available (688 points on my iPad)

Comment: I still don't know what is causing this but have struck upon the workaround of using three picker views rather than one picker view with three components.

Answer (score 1):

After `[[UIPickerView alloc] init]` the Picker has a size of {320,216} and this size will be used in `pickerView:widthForComponent:`. If you just resize the picker afterwards, the function `pickerView:widthForComponent:` won't be called again, so the components are stuck at their width.

Try to initialise the picker with the correct size like..

`picker=[[UIDatePicker new] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds), 216.0)];`

or call `[self.picker setNeedsLayout]` after you change the picker frame to force `pickerView:widthForComponent:` to be called again.